# How can I create a round bevel for this area without creating artifacts?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface, bevel

I've been trying to figure out how to do this sort of procedure before and I've never gotten close to figuring it out until today. I tried using the 'Vertex Group' limit method and I got the curve I'm after but that also bevels every other face on the mesh and if I try and apply only the necessary vertices to the vertex group it creates more artifacts again. I should also mention I'm using a subdivision modifier underneath the bevel modifier. This is what appears to cause the artifacts.

Here's how it looks with just a normal bevel + subdivide: (artifacts are visible around the outer edge)
[image]

Here's how I need it to look:

[image]

But here's what the rest of the mesh looks like when using the vertex group method:
[image]

Also here's an image of the base wireframe without any modifiers:
[image]

Is there any other way around getting the bevel but not creating a bunch of artifacts or bevelling every other face in the process?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  Can you edit your post to include a wireframe view as well?

Comment: Hi, I've just updated the post with a view of the wireframe without any modifiers enabled.

Comment: The inset you've given it looks like a good strategy

Comment: So do you have any idea about what could be the problem or how I could possibly fix the issue?

Comment: After trying it I see where you're struggling :p

Comment: Have you tried enabling autosmooth in the object's data properties -> normals?

Comment: You could try playing around with creasing at the edges.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this kind of topology?

[image]

Begin by creating bevel for the inner edges:

[image]

Then create these edges and delete the useless edges:

[image]

[image]